# Post-installation issue in Cordys

Tags: ldap, cordys-opentext

I am new to Cordys, I am facing the stated issue and have tried everything suggested in the installation guide of CARS 2.4 and Cordys BOP 4.3.
The following post-installation issue is coming:

```xml
<ErrorDetails>
    <Request>
        <SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <SOAP:Body>
                <GetUserDetails xmlns="http://schemas.cordys.com/1.0/ldap"/>
            </SOAP:Body>
        </SOAP:Envelope>
    </Request>
    <Response>
        <SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <SOAP:Body>
                <SOAP:Fault>
                    <faultcode xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">ns0:Server</faultcode>
                    <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">Communication Failure.</faultstring>
                    <faultactor>com.eibus.web.soap.Gateway.wcp</faultactor>
                    <detail>
                        <cordys:FaultDetails xmlns:cordys="http://schemas.cordys.com/General/1.0/">
                            <cordys:LocalizableMessage xmlns:cordys="http://schemas.cordys.com/General/1.0/">
                                <cordys:MessageCode xmlns:cordys="http://schemas.cordys.com/General/1.0/">Cordys.WebGateway.Messages.CommunicationError</cordys:MessageCode>
                                </cordys:LocalizableMessage>
                            </cordys:FaultDetails>
                            <cordys:FaultRelatedException xmlns:cordys="http://schemas.cordys.com/General/1.0/">LDAPException: (40) Failed to send message to [cn=LDAP,cn=soap nodes,o=system,cn=cordys,cn=cordys_43,o=ADNATEITSOLUTIONS.COM]. [com.eibus.exception.BusException: No SOAPProcessor available for: cn=LDAP,cn=soap nodes,o=system,cn=cordys,cn=cordys_43,o=ADNATEITSOLUTIONS.COM] LDAPException: Server Message: Failed to send message to [cn=LDAP,cn=soap nodes,o=system,cn=cordys,cn=cordys_43,o=ADNATEITSOLUTIONS.COM]. [com.eibus.exception.BusException: No SOAPProcessor available for: cn=LDAP,cn=soap nodes,o=system,cn=cordys,cn=cordys_43,o=ADNATEITSOLUTIONS.COM] at com.eibus.directory.soap.LDAPSearchCache.search(LDAPSearchCache.java:466) at com.eibus.directory.soap.LDAPSearchCache.loadCacheValueInternal(LDAPSearchCache.java:235) at com.eibus.util.cache.Cache.loadCacheValue(Cache.java:421) at com.eibus.util.cache.Cache.get(Cache.java:278) at com.eibus.directory.soap.LDAPSearchCache.getLDAPResults(LDAPSearchCache.java:323) at com.eibus.directory.soap.Cache.search(Cache.java:366) at com.eibus.directory.soap.Cache.search(Cache.java:334) at com.eibus.directory.soap.Cache.read(Cache.java:430) at com.eibus.directory.soap.Proxy.read(Proxy.java:458) at com.eibus.directory.soap.LDAPDirectory.read(LDAPDirectory.java:902) at com.eibus.directory.soap.LDAPDirectory.getEntry(LDAPDirectory.java:623) at com.eibus.directory.soap.LDAPDirectory.getURIs(LDAPDirectory.java:639) at com.eibus.transport.Middleware.getInboundURIs(Middleware.java:531) at com.eibus.transport.Middleware.<init>(Middleware.java:199) at com.eibus.transport.Middleware.getInstance(Middleware.java:140) at com.eibus.transport.Middleware.getInstance(Middleware.java:126) at com.eibus.web.gateway.BusGateway.<init>(BusGateway.java:172) at com.eibus.web.gateway.BusGateway.<init>(BusGateway.java:72) at com.eibus.web.gateway.BusGateway.getGateway(BusGateway.java:66) at com.eibus.web.gateway.SOAPTransaction.createConnection(SOAPTransaction.java:1279) at com.eibus.web.gateway.SOAPTransaction.<init>(SOAPTransaction.java:218) at com.eibus.web.gateway.SOAPTransaction.<init>(SOAPTransaction.java:192) at com.eibus.web.soap.Gateway.service(Gateway.java:75) at com.eibus.web.isapi.WebApplication.handleExtensionControlBlock(WebApplication.java:93) at com.eibus.web.isapi.ExtensionControlBlock.execute(ExtensionControlBlock.java:100) at com.eibus.web.isapi.ExtensionControlBlock.run(ExtensionControlBlock.java:71) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: com.eibus.exception.ExceptionGroup: Failed to send message to [cn=LDAP,cn=soap nodes,o=system,cn=cordys,cn=cordys_43,o=ADNATEITSOLUTIONS.COM]. [com.eibus.exception.BusException: No SOAPProcessor available for: cn=LDAP,cn=soap nodes,o=system,cn=cordys,cn=cordys_43,o=ADNATEITSOLUTIONS.COM] at com.eibus.transport.Middleware.send(Middleware.java:1005) at com.eibus.connector.nom.Connector.send(Connector.java:1152) at com.eibus.connector.nom.Connector.sendAndWait(Connector.java:923) at com.eibus.directory.soap.LDAPSearchCache.search(LDAPSearchCache.java:439) ... 28 more </cordys:FaultRelatedException>
                    </detail>
                </SOAP:Fault>
            </SOAP:Body>
        </SOAP:Envelope>
    </Response>
</ErrorDetails>
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @GeneralFailure: thanks for wanting to improve posts. However, we don't add `code formatting` to product/software names - they are just proper nouns. Use capital initials or all-caps as appropriate instead.

Answer (score 0):

It simply states that the LDAP Service Container (SOAP Processor) is not running. Restart Cordys Monitor Service.